# Fail to restore conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have installed some dependencies that have screwed my conda environment. Having my conda environment activated, I am running `conda list --revisions` I am getting a list. By the date, I would like to select the number 10.

Following the instructions available in the conda documentation, I am trying to restore the environment to that version with:
`conda install --rev 10`

When doing so, I am getting this error:

```
(icca) ➜  ~ conda install --rev 10

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - conda-forge/noarch::packaging==23.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libcurl==7.87.0=h9049daf_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h1a8c8d9_8
  - conda-forge/noarch::jinja2==3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil==2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ipython_genutils==0.2.0=py_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::matplotlib-base==3.6.3=py39h35e9e80_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::json5==0.9.5=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::bleach==6.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pycparser==2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::lz4-c==1.9.4=hb7217d7_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::asttokens==2.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libblas==3.9.0=16_osxarm64_openblas
  - anaconda/osx-arm64::bottleneck==1.3.4=py39heec5a64_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pyopenssl==23.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pkgutil-resolve-name==1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - anaconda/osx-arm64::numpy-base==1.22.3=py39h974a1f5_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::llvm-openmp==15.0.7=h7cfbb63_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libopenblas==0.3.21=openmp_hc731615_3
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::liblapack==3.9.0=16_osxarm64_openblas
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::krb5==1.20.1=h69eda48_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::executing==1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::importlib-metadata==6.0.0=pyha770c72_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-ubuntu==0.83=hab24e00_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::contourpy==1.0.7=py39haaf3ac1_0
  - anaconda/osx-arm64::blas==1.0=openblas
  - conda-forge/noarch::idna==3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libwebp-base==1.2.4=h57fd34a_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libdeflate==1.17=h1a8c8d9_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::unicodedata2==15.0.0=py39h02fc5c5_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::parso==0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::backports.functools_lru_cache==1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::nest-asyncio==1.5.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::tornado==6.1=py39h5161555_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::python-fastjsonschema==2.16.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::wcwidth==0.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::beautifulsoup4==4.11.2=pyha770c72_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pyparsing==3.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::terminado==0.17.1=pyhd1c38e8_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::entrypoints==0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ptyprocess==0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::anyio==3.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::appnope==0.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::gettext==0.21.1=h0186832_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pandocfilters==1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - anaconda/osx-arm64::scipy==1.7.3=py39h2f0f56f_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::xorg-libxau==1.0.9=h27ca646_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::freetype==2.12.1=hd633e50_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::pandoc==2.19.2=hce30654_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::typing-extensions==4.4.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pytz==2022.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::matplotlib==3.6.3=py39hdf13c20_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ipympl==0.9.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono==2.37=hab24e00_0
  - anaconda/noarch::threadpoolctl==2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libkml==1.3.0=h41464e4_1015
  - conda-forge/noarch::tomli==2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::snappy==1.1.9=h17c5cce_2
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libjpeg-turbo==2.1.4=h1a8c8d9_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h1a8c8d9_8
  - conda-forge/noarch::decorator==5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::fonts-conda-ecosystem==1=0
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbformat==5.7.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::mistune==2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::defusedxml==0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_server==2.19.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::send2trash==1.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-pandoc==7.2.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::curl==7.87.0=h9049daf_0
  - anaconda/osx-arm64::numexpr==2.8.1=py39h144ceef_2
  - conda-forge/noarch::babel==2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::jpeg==9e=he4db4b2_2
  - conda-forge/noarch::urllib3==1.26.14=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::prompt-toolkit==3.0.36=pyha770c72_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pure_eval==0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::lcms2==2.14=h481adae_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::freexl==1.0.6=h1a8c8d9_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::zipp==3.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::webencodings==0.5.1=py_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_client==7.3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::zstd==1.5.2=hf913c23_6
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::pillow==9.4.0=py39h8bbe137_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::nspr==4.35=hb7217d7_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::fontconfig==2.14.2=h82840c6_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libcblas==3.9.0=16_osxarm64_openblas
  - conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_server==1.23.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::sniffio==1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libev==4.33=h642e427_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::backcall==0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-source-code-pro==2.038=h77eed37_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ipython==8.9.0=pyhd1c38e8_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::xorg-libxdmcp==1.1.3=h27ca646_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::c-ares==1.18.1=h3422bc3_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::pixman==0.40.0=h27ca646_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::blosc==1.21.3=h1d6ff8b_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libedit==3.1.20191231=hc8eb9b7_2
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libgfortran5==11.3.0=hdaf2cc0_27
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbclient==0.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert==7.2.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::backports==1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - conda-forge/noarch::pickleshare==0.7.5=py_1003
  - conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-inconsolata==3.000=h77eed37_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h1a8c8d9_8
  - conda-forge/noarch::six==1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::stack_data==0.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_pygments==0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::zeromq==4.3.4=hbdafb3b_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::bzip2==1.0.8=h3422bc3_4
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::ipykernel==5.5.5=py39h32adebf_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::affine==2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::click-plugins==1.1.1=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::nss==3.78=h1483a63_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::kiwisolver==1.4.4=py39haaf3ac1_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotli==1.0.9=h1a8c8d9_8
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libxcb==1.13=h9b22ae9_1004
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libgfortran==5.0.0=11_3_0_hd922786_27
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::pthread-stubs==0.4=h27ca646_1001
  - conda-forge/noarch::pexpect==4.8.0=pyh1a96a4e_2
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libpng==1.6.39=h76d750c_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::notebook-shim==0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::platformdirs==2.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::websocket-client==1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libssh2==1.10.0=h7a5bd25_3
  - conda-forge/noarch::attrs==22.2.0=pyh71513ae_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libglib==2.74.1=h4646484_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::jedi==0.18.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::json-c==0.16=hc449e50_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-core==7.2.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::fonttools==4.38.0=py39h02fc5c5_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::soupsieve==2.3.2.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::poppler==22.12.0=h9564b9f_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotli-bin==1.0.9=h1a8c8d9_8
  - conda-forge/noarch::pygments==2.14.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema==4.17.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::snuggs==1.4.7=py_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions==4.4.0=pyha770c72_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libnghttp2==1.51.0=hae82a92_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::argon2-cffi==21.1.0=py39h5161555_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h5161555_1001
  - conda-forge/noarch::requests==2.28.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::expat==2.5.0=hb7217d7_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::prometheus_client==0.16.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::click==8.1.3=unix_pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::cairo==1.16.0=h73a0509_1014
  - conda-forge/noarch::traitlets==5.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::notebook==6.5.2=pyha770c72_1
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::libsodium==1.0.18=h27ca646_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::charset-normalizer==2.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::importlib_resources==5.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-arm64::giflib==5.2.1=h27ca646_2
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbclassic==0.4.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::poppler-data==0.4.11=hd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::cycler==0.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pysocks==1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
  - conda-forge/noarch::cligj==0.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::tinycss2==1.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::munkres==1.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - anaconda/noarch::joblib==1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::fonts-conda-forge==1=0
```

Why is it failing to restore? I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: In the help page for `conda install` they show the option as `--revision` not `--rev`. Can you try `--revision`? https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

Comment: @darthbith I just tried with `conda install --revision 10` and I am getting the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56190556/2449192

Comment: I’d guess you don’t actually have `conda-forge` added to your channel configuration, as per darthbith’s comment. See suggested duplicate. Note using the `-c` argument for *ad hoc* channel specifications is prone to yielding unreproducible environments.